# Enabling "Native code debugging" throws ntdll.dll exception in an Outlook addin

Tags: visual-c++, outlook, visual-studio-2019, vsto, visual-studio-debugging

I have a VSTO Addin for Outlook built in C#. It has references to ohter DLLs built in VC++.
I all my VC++ DLLs I have set debug type as "Native Only" instead of "Auto". Now I am trying to enable the option "Enable native code debugging" for my VSTO Addin in "Project settings\Debug\Debugger engines" but when I enable it and start VSTO Addin to debug it, a few error messages are thrown related to ntdll.dll:

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFA5355FCBC in OUTLOOK.EXE: Microsoft C++ exception: windows_exception_impl<0> at memory location 0x000000000014E3A8.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFA5355FCBC in OUTLOOK.EXE: Microsoft C++ exception: windows_exception_impl<0> at memory location 0x000000000014E3A8.
'OUTLOOK.EXE' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\oleaut32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
OUTLOOK.EXE has triggered a breakpoint.

Exception thrown at 0x00007FFA57B81083 (ntdll.dll) in OUTLOOK.EXE: 0xC00000AA: An attempt was made to execute an instruction at an unaligned address and the host system does not support unaligned instruction references.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFA57C68404 (ntdll.dll) in OUTLOOK.EXE: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000.

Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFA57B81083 (ntdll.dll) in OUTLOOK.EXE: 0xC00000AA: An attempt was made to execute an instruction at an unaligned address and the host system does not support unaligned instruction references.
```

If I disable "Enable native code debugging" the VSTO Addin works fine without problems. My VSTO Addin has set debug as configuration and x64 as platform.

Comment: Does VS continue running if you hit F5 after that exception?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko No, it doesn't. It continues showing the exception indefenitely.

Answer (score 0):

The answer has been given in the error message:

> 0xC00000AA: An attempt was made to execute an instruction at an unaligned address and the host system does not support unaligned instruction references.

Outlook doesn't allow debugging using unaligned addresses. You can read more about that in the [Unaligned accesses in C/C++: what, why and solutions to do it properly](https://blog.quarkslab.com/unaligned-accesses-in-cc-what-why-and-solutions-to-do-it-properly.html) article.